# trackpad not working at all after installing ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows, touchpad, windows-10

My trackpad isn't working anymore in my windows OS after installing a ubuntu 16.04.1. I already checked the configurations and set the bios to the default settings.. and still, isn't working :/

Comment: Ubuntu installation won't effect Window's driver files, nor will it change the BIOS.

Comment: Do the trackpad works in ubuntu ? Are you sure trackpad is problem free for now to work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have accidentaly pressed the toggle trackpad button (Fn+Fsomething). Try pressing it again.